# Kafka connect could not find JdbcSinkConnector even if it's installed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have installed JDBC connector running `confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.2.5` inside my kafka connect connector, but when I try to implement a new sink using I have the following error : Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector

Sink I'm trying to use

```
{
    "name": "jdbc-sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "my_topic",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://ip:port/postgres",
        "connection.user": "postgres",
        "connection.password": "PASSWORD",
        "auto.create": "true"
    }
}
```

I'm using confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:6.1.0 image

If I build an image with confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.2.5 and use this image it works.
So looks like we need to restart kafka connect after install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we need to restart kafka connect after install ?

Yes, the JVM doesn't pick up new plugins until (re)started